# /tmp file name collisions when hosting hundreds of small Drupal sites

Tags: drupal, web-hosting, tmp

We host a few hundred small Drupal 6 & 7 websites on a single Debian virtual machine. Each of these sites has it's own Drupal code base and database.

When we had each site using `/tmp` as the "Temporary files" folder in Drupal, we would occasionally have file name collisions across sites.

Is making a `/tmp/site_name` folder for each site our only option to stop these file collisions?

Comment: Why not use php.net/tmpfile or php.net/tempnam so it's getting a random file name?

Answer (score 0):

Multisite doesn't make sense when you do multiple sites for many clients. They are on different boxes sometimes (their hosting), and it just is cleaner to have version control for each site/drupal folder vs trying to put 200 sites in 1 svn project for the 200 clients. For us, we had a demo server for each of these sites. and standalone folders mapped to demo1.test.com, demo2.test.com... I got some issues when duplicating a site to another test subdomain server. The error had some /tmp message in it and some other complaints and Denied Access to my site. The error seemed to go away after refreshing the site. but not sure if visiting many sites at a time will cause issue to popup again... Maybe in the long run it makes sense to have a special tmp folder for each site. maybe like you suggested /tmp/site_name or ../tmp if can use file structure like: /var/www/vhosts/site1/public (for drupal sites) /var/www/vhosts/site1/tmp (for tmp dir)... not sure what perms to give it though.

Answer (score -1):

try to install [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) on your virtual server, as it will help you a lot

Answer (score -1):

Drupal provide multisite concept where you can use same module for all sites.
https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site